# Find the velocity field of ideal fluid that has a sink strength of $2\pi k$ using complex analysis.

Tags: complex-analysis, applications, fluid-dynamics

The precise question is, find the velocity field of ideal fluid given that the fluid has a sink of strength $2\pi k$ at the origin (and no other singularities) and that it has velocity $V_\infty$ (a complex number) at infinity.

This is all the given information. I'm not really to sure where to begin. Any pointers would be appreciated! Thanks!

*EDIT*
This is what I've come up with:

We have
$$
\phi(z)=-\frac{2\pi k}{|z|}=\phi(x,y)=-\frac{2\pi k}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},
$$
which gives the velocity field
$$
v(z)=v(x,y)=\nabla\phi(x,y)=\frac{2\pi kx}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}+i\frac{2\pi ky}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}
$$
Now, as $z\to\infty$ we have $v\to0$. However, at infinity we must have
$$
\lim_{z\to\infty}v(z)\equiv V_\infty
$$
So, the velocity field becomes
$$
v(x,y)=\frac{2\pi kx}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}+i\frac{2\pi ky}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}+V_\infty=\frac{2\pi k}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}(x+iy)+V_\infty,
$$
which gives the result.

Comment: Welcome! What things do you know about the background of the problem?

Comment: Thanks! I actually took some time to think about it, this is what I've come up with.

Comment: In terms of background, I'm not sure what you mean. It's a question on the applications of complex analysis. I hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

From what I know about ideal fluids, the potential should be a harmonic function, which $1/|z|$ is not. I think the correct potential is 
$$\phi(z) = -k\log |z|$$
 The constant $2\pi$ appears naturally:  $\Delta \phi$ is $ - 2\pi k\delta $ where $\delta$  is the Dirac delta at $0$.

The real gradient can be taken using complex notation: 
$$
\nabla \phi = \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z} (2\phi) = \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z} (-k\log|z|^2 ) =  \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z} (-k\log z - k\log \bar z ) = -\frac{k}{\bar z} = -\frac{kz}{|z|^2}$$
Add $V_\infty$ to get the right behavior at $\infty$, as you did.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about the harmonicity of the function.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I find in my (40 years old) notes:
$$
  \oint v_r\,ds = \int_0^{2\pi} v_r\,r\,d\theta = v_r\,r\,2\pi = -Q = -2\pi k
  \qquad \Longrightarrow \qquad v_r = -|u+i\,v| = -\frac{k}{r}
$$
So, for that sink, when augmented with the velocity field at infinity:
$$
   u + i\,v = - \frac{k}{r} e^{i\,\theta} + V_\infty = - \frac{k}{r^2} \left[\,r \cos(\theta) + i\,r\sin(\theta)\,\right] + V_\infty  = 
   - \frac{k\,(x+i\,y)}{x^2+y^2} + V_\infty
$$
Furthermore:
$$
   u - i\,v = -\frac{k}{r} e^{-i\,\theta} + \overline{V_\infty}
   = -\frac{k}{z} + \overline{V_\infty} = \frac{d\phi}{dz}
$$
So the complex potential $\phi$ is (still apart from a complex constant):
$$
  \phi = - k\,\ln(z) + \overline{V_\infty}\, z
$$
Which is all a bit different from the other answers.