# Future learning for a math graduate in applied mathematics references

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation, applications, reference-works

As a mathematics graduate with focus on programming we did a whole lot of coding of some mathematical statements (as well as proving them), but yet rarely giving real life examples and applications for given statements.

So for my future work i would like to learn some of the applications (mostly in electronics, programming, physics...) and get some references where i can continue to learn so that - given a problem i can correlate that to something i have learned before.

**I am most interested in applications for these fields**:

1. Numerical analysis

   - Interpolation (Hermite, multidimensional, Newton, Spline ...)
   - Approximation ( Least squares, uniform approximation,..)
   - Numerical methods for solving differential equations
   - Numerical methods for finding eigenvalues and eigenvectors
   - Numerical Methods for solving non-linear equations

     ...
2. Mathematical analysis

   - Integration by curve, surface
   - Integrals with parameters
   - Fourier series,Fourier transformation,Fourier integral
   - Uniform convergence (for sequence of functions, series, integrals)
   - Weierstrass function, Riemann zeta function

     ...
3. Measure theory

   - Lebesgue measure, Lebesgue integral
   - Radon - Nikodym theorem , derivate
   - Monotone convergence theorem, dominant convergence theorem
   - Lp spaces, norms

     ...
4. Complex analysis

   - Cauchy integral theorem
   - Picard's theorem
   - Laurent series ...
   - Holomorphic functions

     ...

References, books, websites - anything will do, just as long as there are multiple examples (also the more on the side of programming (algorithms, problem solving) and electronics the better)

Comment: This is way too vague, for the Fourier series and PDE the application are all the audio/video signal processing and many physical simulation. And if you want to review all this, my advice would be to start reading a book on the Riemann zeta function and in the same time an introduction to the distribution theory.

Answer (score 2):

Let's check out the OP's wish list:

1. Numerical analysis

   - Interpolation (Hermite, multidimensional, Newton, Spline ...)
     The webpage
     [Programming in Delphi](http://www.alternatievewiskunde.nl/hdb_spul/index.htm#knuth)
     contains some material (theory & software) about interpolation, with 2nd order splines only.
   - Numerical methods for solving differential equations
     My own experience in this field has been summarized as :
     [Highlights](http://www.alternatievewiskunde.nl/origineel.htm)
     .
     (Link, because I don't want this answer look like personal advertizing)
     Research concerns the linear partial differential equations for convection / diffusion.
     And a
     *Least Squares*
     (Finite Element) Method is employed with ideal flow.

   Some of my favorite readings:

   - [Numerical Heat Transfer and Fluid Flow](http://www.ewp.rpi.edu/hartford/~ernesto/F2012/CFD/Readings/Patankar-NHTFF-1980.pdf)
     by [Suhas V. Patankar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suhas_Patankar)
   - [Books by O.C. Zienkiewicz](https://www.goodreads.com/author/list/33854.O_C_Zienkiewicz) (Finite Element Method)

   **Warning.** The mathematics in such practical applications (engineering) books may be very specific, i.e not
   so "general" as is common in "theoretical" treatments. It may contain a lot of hand waving argumentation as well. Looking through all this is part of the challenge. What's more, the two main competitors in Numerical Analysis, the
   [Finite volume method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_volume_method) and 
   [Finite element method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element_method),
   have been invented by *engineers* in the first place, *not* by mathematicians.
   The latter have jumped in (especially with FEM) only after the beef has been roasted already.
2. Mathematical analysis
3. Measure theory
    Somebody somehow has to show me the indispensability of
    *Measure theory*
    for practical applications. Of course, in some of the comments,
    *Probability theory*
    is mentioned as the counter example par excellence. Then we have the following MSE question as a reference:
    [Between bayesian and measure theoretic approaches](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/978406/between-bayesian-and-measure-theoretic-approaches)
    .
4. Complex analysis
    An exellent book is:
    [Complex made Simple](http://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-97)
    , written by one of the top mathematicians in this forum:
    [David C. Ullrich](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/248223/david-c-ullrich)
    . (The book is somewhat less simple than it sounds, though)-:
    EDIT. And indeed, there is no specific Application part in it.
    So here comes a list of Q & A in this forum that is maybe more relevant for the OP:
  - [Find an analytic function that maps the angle $-\pi/4<\operatorname{arg}(z)<\pi/2$ onto the upper half plane so that $w(1-i)=2,w(i)=-1$, and $w(0)=0$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1170372/find-an-analytic-function-that-maps-the-angle-pi-4-operatornameargz-pi)
  - [a problem in application of conformal mappings](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/820189/a-problem-in-application-of-conformal-mappings)
  - [Find the velocity field of ideal fluid that has a sink strength of $2\pi k$ using complex analysis.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603813/find-the-velocity-field-of-ideal-fluid-that-has-a-sink-strength-of-2-pi-k-usin)
  - [How to differentiate Complex Fluid Potential](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/568182/how-to-differentiate-complex-fluid-potential)
  - [Applications of conformal mapping](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/653021/applications-of-conformal-mapping)
  - [How to differentiate Complex Fluid Potential](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/568182/how-to-differentiate-complex-fluid-potential)
  - [CMS : Complex Made Simpler](http://www.alternatievewiskunde.nl/jaar2009/CMS.htm) (?)

Comment: I found wish list funny :)

Comment: Isn't *Measure theory* the basis for **Probability theory**? I don't think I have to stress the importance of the latter for practical applications

Comment: I agree with @YuriyS. The single most important application of measure theory is probability theory. Not to mention quantum mechanics relies on the space $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, where topics such as measurable functions and orthogonal polynomials play a central role.

Comment: @YuriyS: Good response. I've modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Joel: I don't see how functions can be other than "measurable" in quantum mechanics, making it quite a redundant requirement. Am I wrong?

Comment: @snulty i know the 'wish list' sounds random, but it isn't somehow these are the hardest subjects left that rely on other subjects. And we totally didn't give any references for the applications

Comment: @HandeBruijn 
For 4. Complex made simple - reading a quick glance about the book i cannot find the application part - as i said i have the knowledge of how to prove theorems, why a theorem holds when it doesn't hold etc. - I don't need a book showing me just how to prove things. 
The more application there is the better (of course its necessary to list theorems that are being used). That said do you mind just writing what  applications are  listed (and shown) in the book ?

Comment: @YuriyS I had probability and statistics but somehow that was in second year of studies, and measure theory is a third year subject. 
That said we managed to go without it (probably because we didn't go too deep) Do you mind showing where measure theory is used in probability theory (some field - where its used and how we cannot go without measure theory and Lebesgue integral) ? Answer would be nice :)

Comment: @daniels_pa, I'm a physicist, so I'm not the best person to answer you. Just a remark - the basics of probability theory (which I've learned in the third year as well) are not enough for serious quantum mechanics stuff.

Comment: @Joel 
System of orthogonal polynomials is not necessary in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ . But i get your meaning. 
Also somehow that part of Hilbert Space orthogonal projection is EXTREMELY similar to approximation subject in Numerical analysis. So somewhat the application part for those two is the same.

Comment: @daniel_pa Strictly speaking the Hermite polynomials are not in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, but the Hermite functions form an orthonormal basis for $L^2$ and they are made from the polynomials themselves. They are also the eigenfunctions for the time independent Schrodinger eqn for the Harmonic oscillator.

Comment: Moreover, given different measures (or "weight functions") you have a different system of orthogonal polynomials. You are correct that this is intimately related to approximation theory. For instance, for gaussian quadrature, the zeros of orthogonal polynomials are used as sample sites. The polynomials in turn depend on a particular measure.

Comment: @HandeBrujin, each unit vector in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is a measurable function and is called a state in the setting of quantum mechanics.

Comment: @daniels_pa: To be honest, yes, lack of applications, that's precisely the reason why I gave up on it in the end :-( Much related (applied) material can be found at MSE however, if you just search for it.

Comment: @daniels_pa: See my updated answer for a search of my own.

Comment: @HandeBruijn Thats the right path! Though would be great if there were books, websites, articles regarding specific fields (in this case fluid motion) using complex analysis, and not just MSE questions. They somehow got to the point where they need math - i am on the opposite side i have the math but have no idea how they got to need it. And thats the part I'm most interested in. Guiding some non physics people (but instead good at math) towards real world problem where they see the value of their knowledge.

Comment: @daniels_pa: Please read my __warning__ in the updated answer.

Comment: @Joel : when you mention the time independent Schrödinger equation with  a potential $V(x) =|x|^2$, you are thinking also to the higher dimensional problem ?

Comment: @user1952009 the example I was thinking of is the one dimensional example. I'm not sure how well it extends. However, the measure that relates to the hermite polynomials is the Gaussian. It's likely that the results have an extension. I know for instance the related Hilbert space, the Fock space, is often considered in higher dimensions.

Comment: @Joel yes right the Hermite polynomials are the eigenfunctions of the unbounded self-adjoint operator $T : L^2(\mathbb{R},\mu) \to L^2(\mathbb{R},\mu), T u = u''- xu'$ with $d\mu = e^{-x^2}dx$. And you are saying in dimension $\ge 2$ it is not as easy ?

Comment: @user1952009 just saying I hadn't given it much thought. It should extend fairly easily since the n dimensional Gaussian splits as a product of one dimensional gaussians. Why are you so concerned?

Answer (score 2):

Probability theory is to me strictly pure mathematics, but with strong applicable properties. If you like measure theory, along with functional/modern analysis then probability theory is the area for you; The axioms of probability theory (Kolmogorov) are strictly measure theoretic. Then how one builds up expected value and so on is also integration theoretical. One integrates with respect to a probability measure, thus making the Lebesgue integral or equivalent necessary. I **strongly** encourage you to read the table of content in Kallenberg's *Foundations of modern probability theory*, to get a glimpse of what probability theory might entail, from the analytical stand point. It is sadly a bit advanced though, but I do not expect someone to read it all.

Probability theory is to some degree either very analytical or very combinatorial/graph theoretical, i.e. either you get hooked on stochastic analysis and SDE:s (along with stochastic integration and such), or you get hooked on percolation theory and Markov analysis, the latter having intimate connections with statistical mechanics (Ising's model for instance).

And as a last point, probability theory is computationally challenging, in so far as we need strong programmers as well. For instance, Monte Carlo methods are a very popular numerical method.

I hope you do not mind me diverging from your wish list, but I believe probability theory is worth a notice.